# How to fix error when restarting apache2.4

Tags: php, apache2.4

I have multiple php versions installed on my Ubuntu 18.04 - php7.1 php5.6 
When I'm using php7.1 apache restarts successfully. 
But when I switch to php5.6 using this command:

`sudo a2dismod php7.1 ; sudo a2enmod php5.6 ; sudo service apache2 restart`

Apache gives me this error:

```
Job for apache2.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status apache2.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

`systemctl status apache2.service` result:

```
● apache2.service - The Apache HTTP Server
Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/apache2.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
Drop-In: /lib/systemd/system/apache2.service.d
       └─apache2-systemd.conf
Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sat 2018-10-27 13:19:32 +06; 7s ago
Process: 6458 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/apachectl start (code=exited, status=139)

Oct 27 13:19:32 protectedfor apachectl[6458]: AH00112: Warning: 
DocumentRoot [/home/protectedfor/scj] does not exist
Oct 27 13:19:32 protectedfor apachectl[6458]: AH00112: Warning: 
DocumentRoot [/var/www/worldclass/worldclass.kg] does not exist
Oct 27 13:19:32 protectedfor apachectl[6458]: [Sat Oct 27 13:19:32.683512 2018] [alias:warn] [pid 6469] AH00671: The Alias directive in /etc/apache2/apache2.conf at line
Oct 27 13:19:32 protectedfor apachectl[6458]: AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.1.1. Set the 'ServerNa
Oct 27 13:19:32 protectedfor apachectl[6458]: Segmentation fault (core dumped)
Oct 27 13:19:32 protectedfor apachectl[6458]: Action 'start' failed.
Oct 27 13:19:32 protectedfor apachectl[6458]: The Apache error log may have more information.
Oct 27 13:19:32 protectedfor systemd[1]: apache2.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=139
Oct 27 13:19:32 protectedfor systemd[1]: apache2.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Oct 27 13:19:32 protectedfor systemd[1]: Failed to start The Apache HTTP Server.
```

Apache log:

```
[Sat Oct 27 12:43:02.172511 2018] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 6518] AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Sat Oct 27 12:43:10.498278 2018] [so:warn] [pid 5126] AH01574: module php7_module is already loaded, skipping
[Sat Oct 27 12:43:10.544626 2018] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 5137] AH00163: Apache/2.4.29 (Ubuntu) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sat Oct 27 12:43:10.544656 2018] [core:notice] [pid 5137] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Sat Oct 27 12:43:28.243406 2018] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 5137] AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
```

Any advices really appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: check if your local ip is 127.0.1.1 by typing ifconfig(linux) or ipconfig(windows). If it is not you should change your servername at apache.conf

Answer (score 4):

Its not just disable the module. You have to set some defaults in order to make that work

Please try this

set from 7.x to 5.x

```
sudo a2dismod php7.1
sudo a2enmod php5.6
sudo update-alternatives --set php /usr/bin/php5.6
sudo update-alternatives --config php
sudo update-alternatives --set phar /usr/bin/phar5.6
sudo systemctl restart apache2
```

set from 5.x to 7.x

```
sudo a2enmod php7.1
sudo a2dismod php5.6
sudo update-alternatives --set php /usr/bin/php7.1
sudo systemctl restart apache2
```

Comment: lil explanation: a2dismod a2enmod - is for web PHP, update-alternatives - is for PHP CLI . and can be safely executed in 1 line: `sudo a2dismod php7.1 ; sudo a2enmod php5.6 ; sudo service apache2 restart` for web(apache), and this  helps for me everytime!  but sometime status=139 - showing that module loaded/unloaded failed,  so need reenabled _only one_ module(`sudo a2dismod php7.1 ; sudo a2enmod php7.1 ; sudo service apache2 restart`),  and apache  service will start successful!